# Override fields in return object sequelize model nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How can i override one of the return object model in sequelize nodejs?

foe example: i want to override banner field to absolute path when i fetch getAll records.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
User.prototype.toJSON =  function () {
  var values = Object.assign({}, this.get());
values.imagePath = path.join('base/path', values.imagePath);
  return values;
}
```